# maskedtextbox doesn't raise the right value

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, kendo-ui, maskedtextbox

In my view, I used a maskedtextbox for each type of value chosen. For example numeric (15 digits) or bi-numeric (000/000).

```
**Here is the code js:**

// Type bi-numeric
if (_$ddlTypeValeurs.val() == "3") {
                    $("input[name = 'Test.Min']").kendoMaskedTextBox(
                        {
                            mask: "000/000",
                            clearPromptChar: true
                        });
                }
                else {
                    $("input[name = 'Test.Min']").kendoMaskedTextBox(
                        {
                            mask: "00000000000",
                            clearPromptChar: true
                        });

If I choose the bi-numeric type, the Maskedtextebox zone is well formatted at 123/456 or 12/12...

But when I have to raise a value in my base (eg 90/12), the Maskedtextebox displays a value: 901/2 in the place 90/12 :(

**How I can solve this problem ?**

Thanks,
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use 9 for digit or space:
https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/maskedtextbox/configuration/mask

Your mask should look like:

```
{
   mask: "009/009",
   clearPromptChar: true
}
```

9 on the end if you don't want it to be mandatory.

Comment: What is the result?

Comment: 901/2 in the place 90/12 :(